# Subversion Edge SVN cloud solution

Tags: azure, svn, cloud, subversion-edge

At the moment we have a local server as our SVN server, using Subversion Edge 3.1.0, where users push their commits and is used as the main repository. Recently this has been giving us some problems, the server tends to switch off or encounter problems, which then the server needed to be restarted.

Since we also have some people offshore working on the same repository we decided it's best to have an Azure VM set-up, this will act as a backup server and also have the repository updated with each commit (like Dropbox, File Sync, etc.).

My questions are,

- Have anyone actually managed to setup an environment similar to this?
- How do the commits work? When someone pushes to the cloud repository
  and someone then pushes on the local repository.

Answer (score 1):

> Have anyone actually managed to setup an environment similar to this?

As long as you have the networking configured such that users can reach this Azure VM via HTTP (preferably HTTPS), it should be no different from hosting a repository on your company network.

> How do the commits work? When someone pushes to the cloud repository and someone then pushes on the local repository.

Subversion has no notion of a "cloud repository" vs. a "local repository" because it's a centralized VCS - there is only one repository, ever.

Users would simply commit to your Azure-hosted repository instead of the on-premises one. The commits work exactly the same.

> this will act as a backup server and also have the repository updated with each commit

Subversion on its own **is not a backup**! You must take regular backups of your repository and keep them in a location that is separate from the repository server to truly keep your repository data safe.

Your repository will *always* be "updated with each commit" because that's how Subversion works in the first place. Assuming your developers are committing code regularly, that is.